# WhatsApp actual size is in MBs but in iCloud backup it is several GBs

Tags: icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

[image][image]

My actual WhatsApp back total size is 474Mb but when I go to I cloud back up it is showing 10GB, how is it possible? I mean I have deleted all media files from my WhatsApp and in WhatsApp application the total space is 474MB and also in iCloud storage it is 474MB, but when I entered further in to Backups and then choose my phone, it shows total backup size is 14GB and WhatsApp itself is taking 10GB. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

Many people have asked this since it’s not immediately clear that app developers can take up two chunks of storage in iCloud.

1. Data that’s stored directly in iCloud as direct cloud sandbox storage (you have 474 MB in this bucket)
2. Data that exists on the device as local sandbox settings that the OS backs up to iCloud (you have 10 GB in that bucket)

The 14 GB is all the backups and snapshots, so everything looks appropriate to me.